# Time field in EntityForm

Tags: datetime

How can I add a field in my entity form that allows the user to add time.
When I use date, I can add time field but there is always a date field.

I don't want the user to add date field, just the time (for time in and time out). 
And also, I will use the value of that field in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement [Timefield](https://drupal.org/project/timefield) module will be the best choice(considering that you are using Drupal 7)

> Timefield is a Field API field for storing simple non-timezone time
>   values, with an optional end time, utilizing a simple [JQuery
>   timepicker widget](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) for input. Normally, you will want to use a Date
>   field for all date/time values; however, this field is for use when
>   you don't want to implement a Date field or have time values that are
>   not dependent on the Gregorian Calendar, i.e., when Year, Month
>   granularity is irrelevant.

Comment: I have tried using time field. But I have to access the field using query. When I get the values of the field using query, it does not return value in time format. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: What is the issue then, you just need to change the format for time. I think it would not be much tough.

Comment: When I entered `9:00AM` in time field, the value saved in database is `32400` . I dont know what is the meaning of it that's why I can't figure out to change its format.

Comment: It is Unix Timestamp. Use following code to convert timestamp to proper time:

echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$item->timestamp);